# SQL Server: Data import errors

Tags: sql-server, import

I'm trying to import a data set into SQL server and I keep on getting the errror meesages below. I'm not sure what they mean or how to resolve the issue. Its an excel/csv file so I thought there may be line feeds that were causing the issue but I ran the excel clean function on the fields and im still getting the error.

**Error 0xc02020a1:** Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Column 4" returned status value 4 and status text "**Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".**
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

**Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1:** The "output column "Column 4" (26)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Column 4" (26)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

**Error 0xc0202092:** Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "Z:\MandA\x.csv" on data row 1.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

**Error 0xc0047038:** Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - x_csv" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: `Column 4` is certainly not data in your column but the column names itself, are you sure you have set 1st row to skip when importing data as I think it is trying to insert ColumnName into table, there is an option of setting `"1st row Column Names"` make sure you have checked that.

Comment: There are no column names in the first row  in the input dataset. Should there be? I have the field names defined but there data is not populating.

Comment: If thats not the issue then check your field terminator, if it is Comma `,` and you have some data which contains comma in it, SSIS will split the data there on that comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data types are annoyingly different than those in MS SQL, instead of VARCHAR(255) it's DT_STR and the output column width can be set to 255. For VARCHAR(MAX) it's DT_TEXT.

So, on the Data Source selection, in the Advanced tab, change the data type of any offending columns from DT_STR to DT_TEXT (You can select multiple columns and change them all at once).